# Django test not loading fixture data

Tags: django, django-views

I have written tests for a Django project that i am working on, but one particular fixture fails to load.
The fixture is generated using dumpdata and i havent fiddled with it at all.
I can load the data using manage.py on that fixture without errors. I have verified that the data actually loaded using shell and querying the data.
This is driving me nuts, any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my test file (irrelevant portions removed):

```
class ViewsFromUrls(TestCase):
    fixtures = [
        'centers/fixtures/test_data.json',
        'intranet/fixtures/test_data.json',
        'training/fixtures/test_data.json', #The one that fails to load
        ]

    def setUp(self):
        self.c = Client()
        self.c.login(username='USER', password='PASS')

    ...

    def test_ViewBatch(self):
        b = Batch.objects.all()[0].ticket_number
        response = self.c.get(reverse('training.views.view_batch', kwargs={'id':b}))
        self.assertTrue(response.status_code, 200)
    ...
```

Comment: Have you tried just loading that single problematic fixture? Have you tried changing the order of them in the fixtures list? I'd bet you a coffee that it's related to clashing of data in two separate fixtures

Comment: Try with the absolute path to the fixture i.e. /home/user/...

Comment: The problem is they all have the samen name, that they are in different app folders doesn't matter, see my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I Am not sure if this fixes your problem, but on this site:

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Fixtures

I found an interesting remark:

> you see that Django searches for *appnames*/fixtures and
>   settings.FIXTURE_DIRS and loads the first match. So if you use names
>   like testdata.json for your fixtures you must make sure that no other
>   active application uses a fixture with the same name. If not, you can
>   never be sure what fixtures you actually load. Therefore it is
>   suggested that you prefix your fixtures with the application names,
>   e.g. myapp/fixtures/myapp_testdata.json .

Applying this (renaming the fixtures with appname as prefix in the filename), solved my problem (I had the same issue as described here)

Answer (score 37):

Import the TestCase from `django.test`:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class test_something(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['one.json', 'two.json']
    ...
```

- Not: `import unittest`
- Not: `import django.utils.unittest`
- But: `import django.test`

That's a day of frustration right there.
Stop complaining - [it's in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/testing/#django.test.TestCase) :-/

Comment: Heh, and in that very same page (at the top) they specifically tell you to "from django.utils import unittest" :-(  Normally the Django docs are much better than that ...

Thanks for the answer though, it totally helped me out.

Comment: The 'stop complaining' signoff was self-directed and intended as some sort of cryptic final salvo directed at people who justify frustrating design with "well it's all written up in the documentation so the only person to blame for the difficulty is yourself."  Don't read it in the context of some egomaniac who knows the answer but as some pleb like yourself who spent a very frustrating day working out the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Check if the fixture is really in the right place. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/initial-data/#where-django-finds-fixture-files):

> Django will search in three locations
>   for fixtures:
>
> 1. In the fixtures directory of every installed application
> 2. In any directory named in the FIXTURE_DIRS setting
> 3. <strike>In the literal path named by the fixture</strike>

Comment: If he didn't answer your question, why did you mark the answer?

Answer (score 2):

One thing to note, when creating the FIXTURE_DIRS constant in your settings file, be sure to leave out the leading '/' if you have a general fixtures directory off of the root of your project.

Ex: 
'/actual/path/to/my/app/fixtures/'

Now, in the settings.py file: 
Will NOT work: 
FIXTURE_DIRS = '/fixtures/'

Will work: 
FIXTURE_DIRS = 'fixtures/'

It's possible this depends on how your other routes are configured, but it was a gotcha that had me scratching my head for a little while.  Hope this is useful.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

A simple mistake I made was adding a custom `setUpClass()` and forgetting to include `super().setUpClass()` with it (which of course, is where Django's logic for loading fixtures lives)

Answer (score 0):

For me: required TestCase rather than SimpleTestCase! Still don't see the data in postgres after import pdb; pdb.set_trace() but the data is there as reported by my API Call tests..