# Fixtures not loaded during testing

Tags: django, unit-testing, fixtures

I wrote a unit test checking whether initial data is loaded correctly. However the `Node.objects.all().count()` always returns 0, thus it seems as the fixtures are not loaded at all. There is no output/error msg in the command line that fixtures are not loaded.

```
from core.models import Node

class NodeTableTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    fixtures = ['core/core_fixture.json']
    def setUp(self):
        print "nothing to prepare..."

    def testFixture(self):
        """Check if initial data can be loaded correctly"""
        self.assertEqual(Node.objects.all().count(), 14)
```

the fixture `core_fixture.json` contains 14 nodes and I'm using this fixture as a initial data load into the db using the following command:

```
python manage.py loaddata core/core_fixture.json
```

They are located in the folder I provided in the `settings.py` setting `FIXTURE_DIRS`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution in another thread, [answer from John Mee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655038/django-test-not-loading-fixture-data)

```
# Import the TestCase from django.test:

# Bad:  import unittest
# Bad:  import django.utils.unittest
# Good: import django.test

from django.test import TestCase

class test_something(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['one.json', 'two.json']
    ...
```

Doing this I got a proper error message, saying that foreign key is violated and I had to also include the fixtures for the app "auth". I exported the needed data with this command:

```
manage.py dumpdata auth.User auth.Group > usersandgroups.json
```

Using Unittest I got only the message that loading of fixture data failed, which was not very helpful.

Finally my working test looks like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class NodeTableTestCase2(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['auth/auth_usersandgroups_fixture.json','core/core_fixture.json']

    def setUp(self):
        # Test definitions as before.
        print "welcome in setup: while..nothing to setup.."

    def testFixture2(self):
        """Check if initial data can be loaded correctly"""
        self.assertEqual(Node.objects.all().count(), 11)
```

Answer (score 1):

When loading fixtures in test cases, I don't think Django allows you to include the directory name. Try changing your `fixtures` setting to:

```
fixtures = ['core_fixture.json',]
```

You might have to change your `FIXTURE_DIRS` setting as well, to include the `core` directory.

If you run your tests in [verbose mode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---verbosity), you will see the fixture files that Django attempts to load. This should help you debug your configuration.

```
python manage.py test -v 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I included in the FIXTURE_DIRS also the core directory. Whereas I still can load the fixtures with the loaddata command, I get the following error in running the tests: Check if initial data can be loaded correctly ... FAIL

Comment: It might be related to my model signals and some clashing of data. Whereas I do not execute the signal for the loaddata command with "if not kwargs.get('raw', False):", the signal is probably executed while loading the fixtures within a test set. will check it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have your app listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` and that your app contains `models.py` file.